# Google Form File Upload - Send to Slack

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, slack, slack-api

I have a Google Form that is accepting responses and posting each new response to Slack using 'Incoming Webhooks' to track support request tickets. I stated by using the following code from GitHub, and initially encountered no issues and everything was working very well:

https://gist.github.com/akash1810/640a45d5997de1d95f4a

However, I'd now like to now integrate the new Google Form question-type 'File Upload', but the script I'm using in the link does not seem to handle pushing files uploaded through Google Forms to the payload.

The file uploaded through the Google Form appears in the linked Google Sheet (responses) as the direct URL to the file in Google Drive. However, when I view the contents of the variable in Logger it looks like it's the actual file (it shows the Google Drive file ID inside of square brackets). Any suggestions on how to handle passing this to Slack?

Here is the script I'm using (per the link above):

```
/**
 * ABOUT
 * Google Apps Script to post a message to Slack when someone responds to a Google Form.
 * 
 * Uses Slack incoming webhooks - https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks
 * and FormsResponse - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response
 * 
 * 
 * AUTHOR
 * Akash A <github.com/akash1810>
 * 
 * 
 * USAGE
 * Free to use.
 */

// Create an incoming webhook here - https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks
var POST_URL = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX";

function onSubmit(e) {
  var response = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var fields = [
    {"title": "From", "value": e.response.getRespondentEmail()},
    {"title": "When", "value": e.response.getTimestamp()}
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = response[i].getResponse();

    fields.push({"title": question, "value": answer});
  }

  var summaryAttachment = {
    "fallback": FormApp.getActiveForm().getTitle(),
    "pretext": "<!channel> New response submitted to: " + FormApp.getActiveForm().getTitle(),
    "title": FormApp.getActiveForm().getTitle() + " (responses)",
    "title_link": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId(),
    "fields": fields,
    "color": "#393939"
  };

  var responseAttachment = {
    "fallback": FormApp.getActiveForm().getTitle(),
    "title": "Respond via email? (mailto link)",
    "title_link": "mailto:" + e.response.getRespondentEmail() + "?Subject=" + encodeURI(FormApp.getActiveForm().getTitle())
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "username": "Feedback",
        "icon_emoji": ":speech_balloon:",
      "attachments": [summaryAttachment, responseAttachment]
    })
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
}
```

Comment: Where is your research on what the Slack api supports? Are you planning to upload files Slack? Do you just want to link to the file in (someone's) Google Drive? This is your code -  we cannot choose how you want to do it :)

Comment: I think the issue is less of what the Slack api supports and how files are handled in Google Forms. In the Google Forms (responses) Sheet the file appears to be simply a link to the file in Google Drive, so I cannot figure out why the script is catching a file rather than the link from the response trigger.

Comment: Again, the question is - do you want to upload the file to Slack? Or just display a link to the file in Slack? Apps Script can do both. You've not provided a script, logs, or some other concrete way for us to help you further.

Comment: I would like to upload the file to Slack in-line with the message. I've edited the original message to display the script I'm using from the link. In the logs from the script, the only issue is that when "values" is pushed to "fields", I'm not certain what it pushes. In the Google Sheet (responses) that is linked to the Google Form, there is a link displayed for the "File upload" standard form question. However, the "responses" event in the Google Script seems to have a file since this logger shows the "value" of the file is the Google Drive file ID within square brackets.

Comment: Based on the link in that function description - https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks - there's not explicit support for a *file upload* in the webhook. So, I think the first approach to try is to simply make a Slack attachment that has a link to the file in drive.  That drive link can be obtained by `DriveApp.getFileById(theId).getUrl()`. You may need to use `File#setSharing()` to make the file sharable first.

Comment: Can confirm. Slack does not support file uploads on incoming webhooks. You need to use the Web API instead.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, was hoping someone had a method to to do this, but I'll link the file instead.